# Please Explain Simultaneous In/Out Swaps of Same Coin from Same Wallet

Tags: cryptocurrency

I see frequent trades of the same token in the same wallet in the same minute. What is going on?

For example, this pair of swaps in and out of AIOZ are from the same wallet:

Out:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf306745eef0ea056d28df0a70a0b78c8544b2cb2421697a55371345486c74320

In
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x827313545c9fe2c3f5990d11e728c9c9be7f4f1581a1107c5f75a4b97cb5f1ad

Thanks.

Comment: I have been in IT for over 30 years and have recently begun trading crpto. I noticed an interesting pattern in crypto transactions which I'm not able to figure out. I've summarized it into a succinct summary, including links to the transactions on etherscan. I know darn well that this answer is not easily found. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me why this question would be down voted. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer from a blockchain dev:

> The account you're referring to has been doing it since day 1 with
> large amounts in the order of $20k to $30k almost never in profit.
> This to me is wash trading to simulate volume. It is a common but
> unspoken practice of new projects until they get up and running with
> legitimate volume. Most CEXs require a certain sustained daily volume
> while other not so reputable ones do not care if it is done through
> wash trading. This behaviour usually dies down shortly after CEX
> listings with a reputable project. If it persists too long it is a
> serious warning sign. In this market I would be concerned if wash
> trading goes on longer than 2 months after IDO

Pretty important stuff!

IMHO it is a failure of stack overflow to allow down voting without justification (if at all). Clearly this was not down voted because someone recognized a problem with the question. They had indigestion for all we know. I'm hesitant to post here anymore.